# Polymorphism and with statements

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, contextmanager

Given a class that export .csv files to a database:

```
import luigi
import csv

class CsvToDatabase(luigi.Task):
  # (...)
  
  def run(self):    
    ## (...)
    
    with open(self.input().some_attribute, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as some_dataframe:
      y = csv.reader(some_dataframe, delimiter=';')
      
      ### (...) <several lines of code>
  
  # (...)
```

I'm having problems trying to export a file with ISO-8859-1 encoding.

When I exclude the `encoding` argument from then `open()` function, everything works fine, but I cannot make permanent changes in the class definition (firm's other sectors uses it). So I thinked about the possibility of using polymorphism to solve it, like:

```
from script_of_interest import CsvToDatabase

class LatinCsvToDatabase(CsvToDatabase):
  # code that uses everything in `run()` except the `some_dataframe` definition in the with statement
```

This possibility actually exists? How could I handle it without repeating the "several lines of code" inside the statement?

Comment: Please update your question with an ideal version of `run()` from your new class `LatinCsvToDatabase`

Comment: No, it's not possible given the way the `CsvToDatabase` class appears to be implemented. It needs an `open()` method that could be overridden in a subclass.

Comment: You said that you cannot make changes to `run()` because it will affect other sectors work with the code. However, if you add parameter `encoding` e.g.  `def run(self, encoding='utf-8'):`  and then `with open(self.input().some_attribute, 'r', encoding=encoding) as some_dataframe:` - you can call `run()` with the encoding you like (or `None` for that matter to mimic the default behaviour of `open()`) and still not affect other's work with the code.

Comment: @quamrana The ideia was to just replicate the entire original class, just excluding (or changing) the `encoding` argument from the `open()` function.

Comment: If you update your question with an ideal version of `run()` we can see what the difference is between the two. After all OOP is called "Programming by Difference".

Comment: @martineau Thank you for the answer! Could you please explain what you mean by "be overriden in a subclass"?

Comment: @buran Yeah, I was thinking about that as my last resource, because I didn't want to request external sectors to make a commit. But maybe the "last" will be the "only"...

Comment: Yes. Generally speaking, a subclass can override methods they have inherited from their base class by simply redefining them in their own class definition. See [subclasses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)#Subclasses_and_superclasses). If the base class had a separate `open()` method that it used in its `run()` method to open the file, then you could change how things were opened in your subclass.

Comment: well, if you add new class someone will have to commit anyway. The alternative, as mentioned by @martineau is to inherit from original class, keep the full code of run() method with respective changes.

Comment: To recapitulate: If you cannot make permanent changes in the (base) class definition then subclassing it for this purpose is not feasible.

Comment: @buran The `script_of_interest` is shared among the entire firm, while the script with the new class would be shared only with my sector.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @martineau and @buran for the comments. Based on them, I will request a change in the base class definition that didn't affect other sector's work. It would look like this:

```
import luigi
import csv

class CsvToDatabase(luigi.Task):
  # (...)
  encoding_param = luigi.Parameter(default='utf-8') # as a class attribute
  
  # (...)
  
  def run(self):    
    ## (...)
    
    with open(self.input().some_attribute, 'r', encoding=self.encoding_param) as some_dataframe:
      y = csv.reader(some_dataframe, delimiter=';')
      
      ### (...) <several lines of code>
  
  # (...)
```

And finally, in my script, something like:

```
from script_of_interest import CsvToDatabase

class LatinCsvToDatabase(CsvToDatabase):
  pass


LatinCsvToDatabase.encoding_param = None
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider as an alternative modifying the original class to add a new method `get_cvs_encoding`, which is used by the `run` method:

```py
class CsvToDatabase(luigi.Task):
    ...
    def get_cvs_encoding(self):
       # default:
       return 'utf-8'

  def run(self):    
    ## (...)
    
    with open(self.input().some_attribute, 'r', encoding=self.get_cvs_encoding()) as some_dataframe:
      y = csv.reader(some_dataframe, delimiter=';')
    ...
}
```

And then subclass this as follows:

```py
class MyCsvToDatabase(CsvToDatabase):
    def get_cvs_encoding(self):
        return 'ISO-8859-1' # or None
```

And use an instance of the subclass. I just think this is neater and you can have multiple subclass instances "running" concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

After you posted an answer, I think it's better to post some alternatives.
So, here is your current class, minimal example

```
class A:
    def run(self):
        # some code
        with open('some_file.csv' , encoding='utf-8'):
            pass
        # more code
```

My idea, suggested in the comments - change class A and add parameter `encoding` to `A.run()` with default value `utf-8`. This way the change will not affect others (their existing code that use class A).

```
class A:
    def run(self, encoding='utf-8'):
        # some code
        with open('some_file.csv' , encoding=encoding):
            pass
        # more code
```

Then in your code

```
a=A() # create instance of A
a.run(encoding=None)
```

Now, your idea to add class attribute. This is how you decided to change class A:

```
class A:
    encoding='utf-8'
    
    def run(self):
        # some code
        with open('some_file.csv', encoding=self.encoding):
            pass
        # more code
```

I don't think you need to subclass. With this new class A you can do

```
a=A() # create instance of the new class A
a.encoding=None # note, in run() you use self.encoding and this will work. still A.encoding is utf-8 and others will not be affected.
```

And if you insist to subclass the new class A

```
class B(A):
    encoding=None
```

Then in your code you can use instance of class B.